# addPolylines requires numeric longitude/latitude values – but my values are numeric lat/lng

Tags: r, leaflet

This is a short one (I hope). I'm trying to plot bicycle routes in my city with leaflet. But addPolylines() does not like my code. What's the problem here?

```
api.velo.basel <- "https://data.bs.ch/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=100032&q=&rows=21"
json.velorouten.basel <-  read_json(api.velo.basel)

df.routen <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, json.velorouten.basel[["records"]][[2]][["fields"]][["geo_shape"]][["coordinates"]]))

x <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines(data = df.routen,  lng = ~X1, lat = ~X2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the coordinates are given as list of lists and not as list of numeric. So the produced data.frame has columns of type `list` and not of type `numeric`.
You need an additional `unlist` for each coordinate to get standard numeric columns:

```
df.routen <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(json.velorouten.basel[["records"]][[2]][["fields"]][["geo_shape"]][["coordinates"]], unlist)))
```

Alternatively (and probably more efficient) you can also apply `unlist` to the columns of the data.frame you built.

Comment: Thx, great help =)